# BeautifulSoup: find all tags before stopping condition is met

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a class tag from an HTML file, but only if it is located before a given stopping point. What I have is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://mysite")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
class_extr = soup.find_all("span", class_="myclass")
```

This works, but it finds *all* instances of `myclass`, and i only want those *before* the following text shows in the `soup`:

```
<h4 class="cat-title" id="55">
 Title text N1
 <small>
  Title text N2.
 </small>
</h4>
```

The thing that makes this block unique are the `Title text N` lines, especially the `Title text N2.` line. There are many `cat-title` tags before, so I can't use that as a stopping condition.

The code surrounding this block looks like this:

```
...
<div class="myc">
<a class="bbb" href="linkhere_893">
<span class="myclass">Text893</span>
<img data-lazy="https://link893.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="myc">
<a class="bbb" href="linkhere_96">
<span class="myclass">Text96</span>
<img data-lazy="https://link96.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
</div><!-- This closes a list that starts above -->
<h4 class="cat-title" id="55">Title text N1 <small> Title text N2.</small></h4>
<div class="list" id="55">
<div class="myc">
<a class="bbb" href="linkhere_34">
<span class="myclass">Text34</span>
<img data-lazy="https://link34.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="myc">
...
```

continuing both above and below.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the h4 tag a child of the span.myclass tag ?

Comment: No it isn't. (need more chars)

Comment: So can you please post an example of the HTML structure. Or at least what’s the relation between the h4 and span

Comment: There is no relation. I just want to find all the `myclass` tags *before* that block of text without all those that appear *after* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
page = requests.get("https://mysite")
# Split your page and unwanted string, then parse with BeautifulSoup
text = page.text.split('Title text N2.')
soup = BeautifulSoup(text[0], 'html.parser')
class_extr = soup.find_all("span", class_="myclass")
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer also works. Now I don't know which one to choose.

Comment: I'm going to select this one because it makes explicit use of the text I mentioned to be unique. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

Try using `find_all_previous()`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://mysite")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
stop_at = soup.find("h4", class_="cat-title", id='55') # finds your stop tag
class_extr = stop_at.find_all_previous("span", class_="myclass")
```

This will stop at the first `<h4 class='cat-title', id=55>` tag in the event that there are multiple.

Reference: [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous)

Comment: This also works and it is much more elegant ans succinct, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<html><body><p>
<span class="myclass">text 1</span>
<span class="myclass">text 2</span>
</p>
<h4 class="cat-title" id="55">
 Title text N1
 <small>
  Title text N2.
 </small>
</h4>

<p>
<span class="myclass">text 3</span>
<span class="myclass">text 4</span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all():
    if i.name == 'h4' and i.has_attr('class') and i['class'][0] == 'cat-title' and i.has_attr('id') and i['id'] == '55':
        if i.find("small") and i.find("small").text.strip()== "Title text N2.":
            break
    elif i.name == 'span'and i.has_attr('class') and i['class'][0] == 'myclass':
        print (i)
```

Outputs:

```
<span class="myclass">text 1</span>
<span class="myclass">text 2</span>
```

Comment: Thank you but this won't work because there are many `cat-title` tags before. What makes this block unique is the `Title text N2.` text really (and the `Title text N1` text also, but the former is more relevant). I should have mentioned this since it generates confusion otherwise.

Comment: @Gabriel if you need better answe you should create better example in question.

Comment: @furas I thought it was enough with the block I showed. I'll try to expand it.

Comment: @Gabriel you could create minimal-working-example so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Is this hardened enough or do you need me to harden it further?